# Assert.IsInstanceOfType won't accept Type as argument

Tags: c#, mstest

I'm trying to test that some objects are of a certain type:

```cs
 [TestInitialize]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            exam = new Exam(examId, name, date, templateId);

            tabViewModel = new TabControlViewModel(exam);

            tabs = new List<SingleTabViewModel>(tabViewModel.Tabs);

            // Not using this in the current code, but including here to make
            // clear the expected type of the tabs
            examsTab = tabs[0] as ExamsTabViewModel;
            compareTab = tabs[1] as CompareExamsTabViewModel;
            templatesTab = tabs[2] as TemplatesTabViewModel;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestTabTypes()
        {
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(tabs[0], ExamsTabViewModel);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(tabs[1], CompareExamsTabViewModel);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(tabs[2], TemplatesTabViewModel);
        }
```

But in the assertions, the types are giving the error:

> 'ExamsTabViewModel' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Even though the assertion's signature is

> void Assert.IsInstanceOfType(object value, Type expectedType)

Why isn't this working?

Comment: `typeof( ExamsTabViewModel)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want in *instance* of the [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netcore-3.1) class, not the type name. An easy way to get the former from the latter is `typeof`:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTabTypes()
    {
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(tabs[0], typeof(ExamsTabViewModel));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(tabs[1], typeof(CompareExamsTabViewModel));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(tabs[2], typeof(TemplatesTabViewModel));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your assertions to `Assert.IsInstanceOfType(tabs[0], typeof(ExamsTabViewModel))`, cause you need to provide an instance of `Type`, not the type name.